# Unable to permanently store data in a database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to store registration data in the database. There are two tables - geregistry3 and getypes2. Insertion works normally in getypes2. But while inserting data into geregistry3, it either does not get stored or only one tuple is stored (that too temporarily, goes back to empty on restarting that activity) if I don't close the database with db.close(). There are no exceptions or errors displayed in any logs and stacktraces.

Kindly help!

**GEDatabaseHandler.java**

```
package com.example.akshayjk.attempt1.SQL;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
public class GEDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public GEDatabaseHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

private static final String datatbase="mydatabase.db";
private static final String table_name1="geregistry3";
private static final int database_version=1;

public static final String email="email_id";
public static final String group_name="group_name";
public static final String doe="doe";
public static final String timing="timing";
private static final String create_table1="CREATE TABLE " + table_name1 + "( " + email+" TEXT, "+group_name+" TEXT, "+doe+" NUMBER, "+timing+" TEXT "+ ");";

private static final String table_name2="getypes2";
public static final String group_name1="group_name";
public static final String timings="timing";
private static final String create_table2="CREATE TABLE "+ table_name2+"( "+group_name1+" TEXT, "+timings+" TEXT, "+ doe+" NUMBER );";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(create_table2);
    db.execSQL(create_table1);
    fillGetypes(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name2);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name1);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}

public void fillGetypes(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String[] types={"Bodypump", "Barre", "Cycle 45"};
    int[] times={1200,1230,1630,1700,1730,1745,1830,1900,1930};
    String[]day={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[0]);
    values.put(timings,times[0]);
    values.put(doe,day[0]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);


    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[0]);
    values.put(timings,times[4]);
    values.put(doe,day[0]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[0]);
    values.put(timings,times[3]);
    values.put(doe,day[1]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[0]);
    values.put(timings,times[4]);
    values.put(doe,day[2]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[0]);
    values.put(timings,times[8]);
    values.put(doe,day[3]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[0]);
    values.put(timings,times[0]);
    values.put(doe,day[4]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[0]);
    values.put(timings,times[2]);
    values.put(doe,day[4]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[1]);
    values.put(timings,times[0]);
    values.put(doe,day[0]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[1]);
    values.put(timings,times[3]);
    values.put(doe,day[1]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[1]);
    values.put(timings,times[6]);
    values.put(doe,day[3]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[1]);
    values.put(timings,times[5]);
    values.put(doe,day[4]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[2]);
    values.put(timings,times[4]);
    values.put(doe,day[0]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[2]);
    values.put(timings,times[6]);
    values.put(doe,day[0]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[2]);
    values.put(timings,times[0]);
    values.put(doe,day[1]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[2]);
    values.put(timings,times[6]);
    values.put(doe,day[1]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[2]);
    values.put(timings,times[3]);
    values.put(doe,day[2]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[2]);
    values.put(timings,times[2]);
    values.put(doe,day[3]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;

    values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(group_name1,types[2]);
    values.put(timings,times[0]);
    values.put(doe,day[4]);
    db.insert(table_name2, null, values);;
}

public void addRegister(GroupData groupData){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(email,groupData.getEmailId());
    values.put(group_name,groupData.getgroup());
    values.put(doe,groupData.getdOB());
    values.put(timing,groupData.gettiming());
    // Inserting Row
    try {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+table_name1+" VALUES(?,?,?,?)",new String[]{groupData.getEmailId(),groupData.getgroup(),groupData.getdOB(),String.valueOf(groupData.gettiming())});
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*
    */
}

public boolean isTableExists(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+table_name1+"'", null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}

public List<GroupData> getAllRegister(){
    String[] columns = {
            "*"
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    List<GroupData> groupData=new ArrayList<>();
    // query user table with condition
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name1, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            null,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            null,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                      //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order
    int cursorCount=0;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            GroupData user = new GroupData();
            user.setEmailId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(email)));
            user.setDoB(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(doe)));
            user.settiming(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(timings))));
            user.setgroup(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(group_name1)));
            // Adding user record to list
            groupData.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if(cursor!=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
        cursorCount=cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();


    return groupData;
}

public int checkcount(String exgroup, String Doe, int timing){
    String[] columns = {
            "*"
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // selection criteria
    String selection =  group_name+ " = ? AND "+doe+" = ? AND " +timings+" = ?";

    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {exgroup,Doe, String.valueOf(timing)};

    // query user table with condition
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name1, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                      //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order
    int cursorCount=0;
    if(cursor!=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
        cursorCount=cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();

    return cursorCount;
}

public int checkexists(String email, String exgroup, String Doe, int timing){
    String[] columns = {
            "*"
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // selection criteria
    String selection =  this.email+" = ? AND "+group_name+ " = ? AND "+doe+" = ? AND " +timings+" = ?";

    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {email,exgroup,Doe, String.valueOf(timing)};

    // query user table with condition
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name1, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                      //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order
    int cursorCount=0;
    if(cursor!=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
        cursorCount=cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();

    return cursorCount;
}

public List<GroupData> retTypes(String exgroup){
    Date now=new Date();
    int i;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    String daynow=simpleDateFormat.format(now);
    String[] day={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
    for(i=0;i<day.length;i++){
        if(day[i].equals(daynow))
            break;
    }
    simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    String time=simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    String nowtime=time.replace(":","");
    int timeNow= Integer.parseInt(nowtime);
    nowtime="0"+new Integer(timeNow).toString();
    String[] columns = {
            "*"
    };
    List<GroupData> groupDataList=new ArrayList<GroupData>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // selection criteria
    String selection =  group_name1+" = ? AND " +doe+" IN (?,?,?)";
    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {exgroup,day[i%7],day[(i+1)%7],day[(i+2)%7]};

    // query user table with condition
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name2, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                      //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            GroupData user = new GroupData();
            user.setgroup(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(group_name1)));
            user.settiming(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(timing))));
            user.setDoB(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(doe)));
            // Adding user record to list
            groupDataList.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if(cursor!=null && !cursor.isClosed())
        cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return groupDataList;
}

public List<GroupData> retTypes(String exgroup, String chosenDay){
    Date now=new Date();
    int i;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    String daynow=simpleDateFormat.format(now);
    String[] day={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
    for(i=0;i<day.length;i++){
        if(day[i].equals(daynow))
            break;
    }
    simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    String time=simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    String nowtime=time.replace(":","");
    int timeNow= Integer.parseInt(nowtime);
    nowtime=new Integer(timeNow+1000).toString();
    String[] columns = {
            "*"
    };
    List<GroupData> groupDataList=new ArrayList<GroupData>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // selection criteria
    String selection =  group_name1+" = ? AND " +doe+" = ?";
    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {exgroup,chosenDay};

    // query user table with condition
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name2, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                      //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            GroupData user = new GroupData();
            user.setgroup(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(group_name1)));
            user.settiming(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(timing))));
            user.setDoB(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(doe)));
            // Adding user record to list
            groupDataList.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return groupDataList;
}

}
```

**GE_Form.java**

```
package com.example.akshayjk.attempt1.HFW_Activities;

public class GE_Form extends AppCompatActivity{

public static GEDatabaseHandler gdb;
public List<GroupData> groupData=new ArrayList<GroupData>();
public Spinner spTypes,spDays,spTimings;
public Button button;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(GE_Form.this, HFW.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_geform);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String email = bundle.getString("email");
    button = findViewById(R.id.button_registerge);

    gdb = new GEDatabaseHandler(GE_Form.this, null, null, 4);
    String[] types = {"Bodypump", "Barre", "Cycle 45"};
    String[] days;
    String[] timings;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    final ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> s2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String[] s3;
    final String[] s4;
    spTypes = findViewById(R.id.ge_sp1);
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types);
    spTypes.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spDays = findViewById(R.id.ge_sp2);
    spTimings = findViewById(R.id.ge_sp3);
    final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.test2);
    spTypes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final String group = spTypes.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            groupData = gdb.retTypes(group);
            s1.clear();
            for (GroupData g : groupData) {
                s1.add(g.getdOB());
                textView.append(g.getdOB() + " " + g.getgroup() + " " + g.gettiming() + "\n");

            }
            Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
            hs.addAll(s1);
            s1.clear();
            s1.addAll(hs);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
            adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s1);
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            spDays.setAdapter(adapter2);
            spDays.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String days = spDays.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                    s2.clear();
                    groupData = gdb.retTypes(group, days);
                    for (GroupData g : groupData) {
                        s2.add(String.valueOf(g.gettiming()));
                    }
                    Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
                    hs.addAll(s2);
                    s2.clear();
                    s2.addAll(hs);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3;
                    adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s2);
                    adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    spTimings.setAdapter(adapter3);

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });


            if (groupData.isEmpty()) {
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                String time = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                String nowtime = time.replace(":", "");
                int timeNow = Integer.parseInt(nowtime);
                nowtime = "0" + new Integer(timeNow).toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nowtime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String edex = spTypes.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            String eddoe = spDays.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            int edtime = Integer.parseInt(spTimings.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            GroupData gd = new GroupData();
            if (gdb.checkexists(email, edex, eddoe, edtime) != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (gdb.checkcount(edex, eddoe, edtime) < 5) {
                    gd.setEmailId(email);
                    gd.setDoB(eddoe);
                    gd.setgroup(edex);
                    gd.settiming(edtime);
                    gdb.addRegister(gd);
                    textView.setText("");
                }
                    List<GroupData> groupData1 = gdb.getAllRegister();
                    if (groupData1.isEmpty())
                        textView.append("Not writing into table");
                    for (GroupData d : groupData1) {
                        textView.append("\n" + d.getEmailId() + " " + d.getgroup() + " " + d.getdOB() + " " + d.gettiming());
                    }
                        if (gdb.isTableExists()) {
                            textView.append("Exists");
                        } else
                            textView.append("Does not exist");
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation, you find that passing `null` as the database name, creates an in-memory database, which means that it is not persisted.
[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int))

So try passing any database name (just any string) when you are creating `GEDatabaseHandler`.

After that check if your data is persisted correctly.